# after submission contact form7 data insert into different database table

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, mysqli

My website in wordpress. I want to send automatically contact form 7 value to different database table. For example one is wordpress database table & another one is php database table. how i can fixed this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving contact form 7 data into custom db and not wordpress db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231918/saving-contact-form-7-data-into-custom-db-and-not-wordpress-db)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the Below Steps and add code in functions.php:

1) Create custom table in your custom database

```
 CREATE TABLE candidate(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(50)
);
```

2) Create contact form 7 fields

```
[text* title]
[submit "Send"]
```

3) Add Below code to function.php

```
  function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {
    //set your db details
    global $wpdb;

    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB ) 
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
    $title = $formData['title'];

    /************* Insert in wordpress database ***********/
    $wpdb->insert( 'candidate', array( 'title' =>$title ), array( '%s' ) );

    /************ For Php Mysql Database (Create connection first) ********/
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (title)
    VALUES ($title)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add below code to your function.php file.**

```
function custom_db_wpcf7_before_send_mail($form7_data) {
    //set your database details
    $custom_db = new wpdb('user','password','custom_db','host');

    $form7_data = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($form7_data) 
        $post_data = $form7_data->get_posted_data();
        $title = $post_data['title'];
        $custom_db->insert('custom_table', array('field' => $value), array( '%s' ));
    }
    remove_all_filters('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
    add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'custom_db_wpcf7_before_send_mail' );
}
```