# I use "Saving contact form 7 data into custom db and not wordpress db method, and file upload does not save to the directory anymore

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, asyncfileupload

Saving contact form 7 data into custom db and not wordpress db

[Saving contact form 7 data into custom db and not wordpress db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231918/saving-contact-form-7-data-into-custom-db-and-not-wordpress-db)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders

The upload file will be stored in the table however, actual file does not store in the server side anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this i think .Saving contact form 7 data into custom db and not wordpress db was , removing the picture after sending the picture to the email, so has to use the move function refer to the https://alohajay.org, i write more on those later in code level.