# Saving data from a contact form 7 "selection field" in a custom database and not in a wordpress database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, code-snippets, contact-form-7

hello who can help me i can not retrieve the data of the selection field in my database. That's what I do following this example [Saving contact form 7 data into custom db and not wordpress db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231918/saving-contact-form-7-data-into-custom-db-and-not-wordpress-db/50232256#50232256) but it doesn't work

1. I create the table

```snippets
 CREATE TABLE test(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  city VARCHAR(50)
);
```

2. I Create the form in CF7

```html
 [select city "New York" "Miami" "London"]
 [submit "OK"]
```

3. And here is the code in function.php

```snippets
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {
    //connexion to database
   
   $mydb = new wpdb('locacarm_rent2','Sam2005','locacarm_rent2','localhost');;

     $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB ) 
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
 
    $city = $formData['city'];

     
  $mydb->insert( 'test', array('city' =>$city ), array('%s') );
            
    

}
remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data in the dropdown (select) is stored as an array.  Try this.  It's more concise and uses the `$submission` which is already passed to `before_send_mail` as the third parameter.

Keep in mind, that you should sanitize your input - even with a `<select>` as someone could post the data without your form. Contact form 7 does not sanitize input fields for insertion into a database.

```
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
    // connexion to database.
    $mydb = new wpdb( 'locacarm_rent2', 'Sam2005', 'locacarm_rent2', 'localhost' );
    if ( $submission ) {
        $form_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $city      = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $form_data['city'][0] ) );
        $mydb->insert( 'test', array( 'city' => $city ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail', 10, 3 );
```